# dnn upgrade of 7.0.5 to 7.1.1 install/provider zip files error

Tags: dotnetnuke, upgrade, dotnetnuke-7

I had an error during an in place upgrade of DNN 7.  the error occured during the installation of the new providers from the install/providers folder.  SPecifically i think it was during the rad editor provider upgrade.

here is the error:

> 2013-08-27 17:40:54,149 [WS048][Thread:6][FATAL]
>   DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication -
>   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.ZipException: System.ApplicationException:
>   Unknown block type 7    at
>   ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Inflater.Decode()    at
>   ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] buf,
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously) 2013-08-27 17:42:59,589
>   [WS048][Thread:6][ERROR]
>   DotNetNuke.Common.Internal.ServicesRoutingManager - Unable to register
>   service routes System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()    at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
>   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes)
>   at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.<.cctor>b__0()    at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

This makes me think it was a blocked zip file, but I double checked to make sure the zip file was unblocked

**Question:**  Does someone know where this error comes from?  Or how can I figure out more specifically where it is comming from

thanks

## EDIT #1

So I restored from a backup and tried again, I got the same error but at a different install/provider zip file.  I am not sure what is causing this.  This error seems to indicate the zip files are corrupted and are not downloaded/uploaded correctly.

## EDIT #2

is there a chance that my ftp client is corrupting the zip files during upload? This has been going on for three days with well over a dozen different attempts to upgrade to various versions.  I've never had this difficulty with a dnn upgrade ever and I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible that you're getting corruption issues somewhere.

I would start by downloading the UPGRADE package again, extracting them using 7zip instead of Windows Compression, then try the upload. Maybe try a new FTP client, or see if you can RDP into the machine instead of FTP

Comment: when I download the 711 package, the telerik files are missing from the bin folder, is that an error or is that the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: Those are unzipped automatically by DNN during the install to ensure that the upgrade can run

Comment: @MitchelSellers thanks for clarifying, they are the wrong version in the 711 upgrade and I had to correct the version number in web.config.  Once I did that the error above was generated